# Optimal way to query an item inside a list attribute in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a table which has a list attribute. I want all the records with some value X in the list.

I am aware of `contains` which scans the table. However, I want to do it as optimally as possible.

I have normalized the list attribute and stored it in a new table along with PK of the first table. Then I query the table for a value and then query the original table.

Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should denormalize the list attribute and store every value in the list as its own DynamoDB item, then you can create and index on that attribute which will allow you to search it efficiently.

There's pros and cons to that method and without understanding your specific use case it's the most optimal way I can suggest.